# How can I add an application to the GNOME application menu?

Tags: gnome3

I have an application that I start only from the command line. How can I add the command (and preferably a nice logo) to Gnome's application menu?

Comment: If you right click do you get an "Edit Menu" item?

Comment: no, no right click menu at all.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/792067/how-to-edit-the-applications-menu-in-gnome-3

Answer (score 158, accepted):

In [GNOME](http://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en) and other [freedesktop.org](http://freedesktop.org)-compliant desktop environments, such as [KDE](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Desktop_File) and [Unity](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles), applications are added to the desktop's menus or desktop shell via *desktop entries*, defined in text files with the `.desktop` extension (referred to as *desktop files*). The desktop environments construct menus for a user from the combined information extracted from available desktop entries.

Desktop files may be created in either of two places:

- `/usr/share/applications/` for desktop entries available to every user in the system
- `~/.local/share/applications/` for desktop entries available to a single user

You might need to restart GNOME for the new added applications to work.

Per convention, desktop files should not include spaces or international characters in their name.

Each desktop file is split into *groups*, each starting with the group header in square brackets (`[]`). Each section contains a number of *key*, *value* pairs, separated by an equal sign (`=`).

Below is a sample of desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Application Name
Comment=Application description
Icon=/path/to/icon.xpm
Exec=/path/to/application/executable
Terminal=false
Categories=Tags;Describing;Application
```

**Explanation**

- `[Desktop Entry]` the `Desktop Entry` group header identifies the file as a desktop entry
- `Type`           the type of the entry, valid values are `Application`, `Link` and `Directory`
- `Encoding`        the [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) of the desktop file
- `Name`            the application name visible in menus or launchers
- `Comment`         a description of the application used in tooltips
- `Icon`            the icon shown for the application in menus or launchers
- `Exec`            the command that is used to start the application from a shell.
- `Terminal`        whether the application should be run in a terminal, valid values are `true` or `false`
- `Categories`      semi-colon (`;`) separated list of menu categories in which the entry should be shown

Command line arguments in the `Exec` key can be signified with the following variables:

- `%f`  a single filename.
- `%F`  multiple filenames.
- `%u`  a single URL.
- `%U`  multiple URLs.
- `%d`  a single directory. Used in conjunction with `%f` to locate a file.
- `%D`  multiple directories. Used in conjunction with `%F` to locate files.
- `%n`  a single filename without a path.
- `%N`  multiple filenames without paths.
- `%k`  a URI or local filename of the location of the desktop file.
- `%v`  the name of the Device entry.

Note that `~` or environmental variables like `$HOME` are not expanded within desktop files, so any executables referenced must either be in the `$PATH` or referenced via their absolute path.

A full [Desktop Entry Specification](http://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/) is available at the [GNOME Dev Center](http://developer.gnome.org/).

**Launch Scripts**

If the application to be launched requires certain steps to be done prior to be invoked, you can create a shell script which launches the application, and point the desktop entry to the shell script. Suppose that an application requires to be run from a certain current working directory. Create a launch script in a suitable to location (`~/bin/` for instance). The script might look something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
pushd "/path/to/application/directory"
./application "$@"
popd
```

Set the executable bit for the script:

```
$ chmod +x ~/bin/launch-application
```

Then point the `Exec` key in the desktop entry to the launch script:

```
Exec=/home/user/bin/launch-application
```

Comment: I did that, I can see the icon under applications, but when I click the app does not start, the cursor only changes to a loading symbol for a few seconds. No error message.

Comment: @mart Can you tell us which application you are trying to add a launcher for?

Comment: FTL - an indie game I bought somewhere on the web. Starting from Console works.

Comment: to add: from the console, I call the game with cding to the directory and calling it with ./FTL. When I enter <path>/.FTL in the .desktop file, I get the error message that the executable cannot be found. When I leave the dot out, I get the result described above.

Comment: @mart `<path>/.FTL` would point to a hidden file called `.FTL`, which is not the same as `./FTL`, which points to a file called `FTL` in the current directory. You can try to launch `FTL` via `/full/path/path/to/FTL` in a terminal to see if you get any meaningfull error output. For instance, if the executable searches for libraries in the current working directory, you might have to do a launcher script which does something along the lines of `pushd <path>; ./FTL; popd` and point the `Exec` specifier in the desktop file to the launcher script instead.

Comment: launching via /full/path/path/to/FTL works.

Comment: correction: it works from inside the directory

Comment: @mart I updated the answer to provide more details and links to external resources. As I see it, this answer now covers the solution to the extent of your original question. If this does not solve your problem, I suggest you [ask a new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and include the content of the desktop file you created, the exact steps you use to launch the application from a shell, any launch-script you might have tried and the output of `/full/path/to/FTL`.

Comment: This works great for Steam games too. Just use Create Desktop Shortcut action and then mv the .desktop file from Desktop directory to applications.

Comment: dash is the default not just for Ubuntu derived distros, but for all Debian derived distros'.

Comment: I used 'sudo dnf install alacarte' to get this done. https://askubuntu.com/questions/79583/adding-custom-applications-to-gnome-launcher

Comment: Pay attention if your file already contains a `NoDisplay=true` row.. after putting this line to **false**, everything works like a charm. No need to restart GNOME.

Answer (score 18):

Very good answer from Thomas Nyman.

Gnome comes with gui tool `gnome-desktop-item-edit` assisting in creating *.desktop files.
We need to use it from command line, or create a desktop file for it.

#### Instructions to make Gnome Application from `gnome-desktop-item-edit`

1. Open terminal windows and type the following command:

   ```
   gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new /home/[your user name]/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. In the opened window fill the following:

[image: gnome-desktop-item-edit]

`Name: Gnome Applicaiton`

`Command: gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new /home/[your user name]/.local/share/applications`

Click on the icon to select a different icon.

3. Click OK to close the windows
4. Close the terminal window

#### Testing newly generated  `Gnome Application`

1. Open dash
2. Type Application
3. You should see the  `Gnome Application` entered before
4. Select it
5. Create another application

#### To create for all users use:

```
sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new /usr/share/applications
```

#### If the command is missing on debian/ubuntu try:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

Comment: This works really well, thanks. Is there any way to alter which menu the new application appears in ? Mine appeared in Applications->Other

Comment: That command is unavailable in Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: This command is also unavailable in CentOS 8, has it been deprecated? Or is there a way to somehow install this package?

Comment: It seems the command is removed (since 3.32?) https://askubuntu.com/q/1184733/ https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-panel/commit/758b548aa9d2b920b6e91664b0de9c414b65f2e9

Comment: Is there any alternative after @hashlash's finding?  There's neither a `gnome-desktop-item-edit` nor a `gnome-panel` to `sudo yum install` on RHEL 4.18.

Answer (score 8):

A graphical solution is to install MenuLibre

It is available for Ubuntu-flavored distributions via

```
apt install menulibre
```

or you can install it from [source](https://github.com/bluesabre/menulibre)

It allows to categorize apps per Gnome categories and plays well with Chrome apps.

[image: Menu Libre]

Comment: This should be the best answer

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers from Thomas Nyman and Dudi Boy are very good and detailed. I am posting this because I didn't found a answer for my doubt in any other posts and I had to search in git issues.

After I followed the steps like Thomas Nyman suggested I have been able to make the icon for my program to appear in the App Menu. The problem here is that I use Dash to Dock as side bar and I could not pin the icon as a favourite like other icons. After searching I found that you need to add the line `StartupWMClass=ApplicationName` in `.desktop` file.
After that the option to add to favourites will appear by right clicking on the icon in Dash to Dock.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for AndroidStudio.

Stay on the location ~

`vi .local/share/applications/androidstudio.desktop`

Then add the configuration

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=2022.3.1 Patch 2
Name=Android Studio
Comment=Android Studio for linux
Type=Application
Icon=/home/mariot/Downloads/android-studio-2022.3.1.20-linux/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Exec=sh /home/mariot/Downloads/android-studio-2022.3.1.20-linux/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;
```

Set grants with the command:

```
gio set .local/share/applications/androidstudio.desktop "metadata::trusted" yes
```

Then if all the paths are corrects you could test with:

```
gio launch .local/share/applications/androidstudio.desktop
```

You could launch the application since the search launcher.

Greetings.