# Change executable reference for app icon in in GNOME 3 launcher

Tags: bash, shell-script, virtualbox, gnome3, gnome-shell

I've created a custom script to launch VirtualBox that replaced the original script in ¸/usr/bin/¸. So running VirtualBox in a terminal launches my script. However, pressing <kbd>super</kbd> key and type "virtualbox" in Gnome Shell launcher brings the old original script.

How can I change that behavior so that when I type *virtualbox* in Gnome Shell launcher my custom script runs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look for the file `/usr/share/applications/virtualbox.desktop`. On my system, it has the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=Oracle VM VirtualBox
GenericName=Virtual Machine
Type=Application
Exec=VirtualBox %U
...
```

Simply change the `Exec` part to point to your custom executable/script.

**See also**

Thomas Nyman's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103222/26909) to a similar question.

Comment: Perfect! thanks. The thing that's weird is that when I run the command "locate virtualbox.desktop" the output was empty.

Comment: @Rombus No that's not weird. It just means your `locatedb` isn't up-to-date. You need to run `updatedb` first. See `man locate`.