# Into which directory should I install programs in Linux?

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure

I want to install a program in Linux and run it as a daemon. (Team Speak 3 in this case, but the question is general in nature). There is no package provided, only tarred binaries.

Where in the directory structure should I put such a program by convention?

On the web I found that `/opt` is for "optional addon apps", while `/usr` is for "user programs".

I found one tutorial suggesting `/opt` while another suggested `/usr`.

So which one is "more correct"?

Comment: The "more correct" depends on your distribution. You should check your distribution's guidelines on where to put software that isn't managed by the package manager (often `/usr/local`) OR on how to create your own package for it.

Comment: Thank you Leiaz. Your comment helped me to find the answer (http://askubuntu.com/questions/1148/what-is-the-best-place-to-install-user-apps). So I guess it should be /opt in my case (Using Linux Mint, which is based on Ubuntu) and the application is using a single folder. If you convert your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: The convention is bad. Ignore the convention. Make `~/apps` or `~/programs` and put your programs in there. Make `~/apps/binaries` or `~/apps/on-path`, add that to your $PATH env var, and symlink the programs you want into `binaries`.

Comment: @iono Convention is good when you're installing a package that will be used by more than one person. Installation in `/usr/local` is globally accessible, installation in `~onealdw/apps` cannot be accessed by any user other than myself.

Comment: Yes, I was asking here about a program, which would run as a service (daemon) (even when all human users are logged off), not a personal app that some user would run from their home directory.

Comment: @doneal24 Then use `/apps` or `/programs` without the tilde, obviously. The convention is still bad and has been making open-source computing needlessly complex, and therefore inaccessible, and therefore useless to the vast majority of human beings for around 50 years too long to be forgiveable.

Comment: @iono I fail to see any significant difference between the convention of `/usr/local` or `/opt` and `/apps` or `/programs`. After installing open source programs for ~40 years (way before open source was a term), I cannot see how it is needlessly complex. Is `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` any different than `./configure --prefix=/apps`?

Comment: @doneal24 those 40 years of habit are precisely the reason you fail to see the problem

Comment: @iono Then can you explain why using the directories you suggested instead of the traditional directories make installation and use of application less complex? Substituting `/apps` for `/opt` seems to be a no-op.

Comment: @doneal24 sure: "usr" and "opt" and "local" are all completely meaningless symbols, relics of prior poor design choices, whereas "apps" or "programs" just describe their own function in plain English

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The "more correct" depends on your distribution. You should check your distribution's guidelines on where to put software that isn't managed by the package manager (often `/usr/local`) OR on how to create your own package for it.

As you said, TeamSpeak just put everything in one folder (and may not be easy to reorganise), yes `/opt/` is probably best.

(But, for instance, in Arch Linux, the package manager can install there, so I'd still make a PKGBUILD to install in `/opt`.)

Also distributions *usually* try to follow the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html), so this is where to look for more generic conventions.

Comment: is there some alias to know where are located each directory by usage? (for example, where to put root configurations, where to put binaries, dependencies, templates...)

Comment: Usually you put your downloaded folder in /opt and create a symbolik link from /usr/bin. If the app has a GUI a very useful thing to do is to create a NAME.desktop file in /home/USER/.local/share/applications such that you will see it from the main menu. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103222/130710

Answer (score 21):

### Where to install a program?

If you will be compiling your own software then you ultimately control the installation location.

- By convention, *software compiled and installed manually* (not through a package manager, e.g apt, yum, pacman) is installed in `/usr/local`.
- *Some packages* (programs) will create a sub-directory within `/usr/local` to store all of their relevant files in, such as `/usr/local/openssl`.
- *Other packages* will install their necessary files into existing directories such as `/usr/local/sbin` and `/usr/local/etc`.
  These are simply default locations and can be changed during
  compilation.

### Define installation location when running ./configure

When you are compiling software, the *installation location can be specified* by using the `--prefix=` option when running `./configure`.  It is highly recommended that you look at all of the available options for your package by running `$ ./configure --help | less`.  Additionally, browsing the `INSTALL` and `README` documents provided with your package is a good idea.  They tend to include installation instructions and dependency information that is specific to the package.

### Please Note

It should also be noted that *although you can store software anywhere*, according to the [FHS](http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier), source code for locally installed software should be stored in `/usr/local/src`!

Standardizing where you store your source trees will allow you to easily locate a tree if you need to copy a stock configuration file or binary.  Even though some packages use it, your source code should not be stored in `/usr/src` as that is designated for system software such as the kernel.

### Ensure your locations is found by PATH

Finally, you need to ensure that your installation location is included in your `$PATH`.  If you decide to install your package in `/opt` but it's not in your `$PATH` your shell won't find the executables and you will have to use the absolute path to invoke your programs. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) are some great discussions from [AU](https://askubuntu.com/) about configuring your `$PATH`

Additional reading: `man hier`

Answer (score 11):

The [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) and the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) are arguably the standards of where and how you should install software on a Linux system. I would suggest placing software that isn't included in your distribution either in `/opt` or `/usr/local/` or rather subdirectories therein (`/opt/<package>  /opt/<provider>  /usr/local/bin`).

Best practice is to convert software you download to an installable software package native to your distribution, for instance dpkg or rpm formats. That will facilitate reporting, upgrading and cleanly removing the software.

Comment: This pretty much just re-states the question rather than answering it. The OP was aware that `/opt` and `/usr/local/` were the two available options but wanted specific information on *which one* of those options to use. This could be a *valid* answer if it instead made a claim that the two locations are interchangeable (although I would dispute that it would be a *correct* answer in such case).

Comment: Is there any specific way to create a installable software package from the software I download (tar.gz) ?

Answer (score 8):

## `~/.local/bin`

This is defined in [systemd's standard](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html#%7E/.local/bin/) which has the following to say about the directory's contents:

> Executables that shall appear in the user's `$PATH` search path. It is recommended not to place executables in this directory that are not useful for invocation from a shell; these should be placed in a subdirectory of `~/.local/lib/` instead. Care should be taken when placing architecture-dependent binaries in this place, which might be problematic if the home directory is shared between multiple hosts with different architectures.

Depending on your distribution, you might have to add the directory to your path by putting this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

See also: [Which distributions have $HOME/.local/bin in $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316765/which-distributions-have-home-local-bin-in-path)

Comment: Only issue with this is that it is on a user base and therefore doesn't apply for when one needs a system-wide install.

Comment: @domsson: Right, when you want to install software for all users, you'd use something different, like `/usr/local/bin`. I encountered the situation more often where I wanted to add software just for my user (also because I'm the only person using that machine). Since `~/.local/bin` is user-writable whereas `/usr/local/bin` is not (at least on Arch), this was the more convenient option for me.

Comment: in some cases when the app is an entire folder, I would use `~/.local/src/programfolder` and make the appropriate call in a .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`

Answer (score 1):

Binaries go in the `bin` folder by common conventions, how you would organize your package structure is up to you, I can think of `/opt/<prog_name>/` if it is just a list of binaries.

Comment: I am afraid that Team Speak 3 guys made the program in such a way that everything it needs sits just in one folder (binaries,config files, logs), so It doesn't use /bin or /etc or /var/log

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question while installing Eclipse via the Eclipse installer.

I noticed that Gimp, Perl and Vim are installed in the `/usr/share` folder and decided to install it there.

Comment: I suppose some auxiliary files may have been installed under that path, but the executables would be found in a `bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways programs can be installed, depending on how they are packed.

1. Via the software manager (apt, synaptic, Gdebi etc.) – the program is in a form of package, usually .deb or rpm. Software managers in most cases handles dependencies and will install binaries usually into `/usr/bin`, config files into `/etc` and so on. They may also create a config file for the program in your home, usually `~/.foo`. If you can edit this file, you can also easily change settings for your session this way. When you remove the package, the manager will find all the files and cleanly remove them (it stored all the locations in a special text file). But it may preserve some config files, for example the one in your home folder.
2. You download a program (usually compressed) in a form of pre-compiled binary files for your architecture. The executable file of the program is usually in a single folder next to other files (dynamically linked libraries etc.) This whole folder can be copied, with root privileges, either to `/opt` or `/usr/bin` and could, if permissions allow, be used by any user. I myself put the folders with binary files into my home folder to `~/bin`. Now you should be able to run the program by invoking its bin file.

Answer (score -4):

Don't use any of the pre-existing OS directories like `usr`. There is no well-defined standard which other people hold to consistently, and so:

- you'll end up having to track many, many poorly-named locations,
- you'll run into situations where it's ambiguous where you should store your program (as evidenced by the popularity of this question and complexity of its answers), and
- programs you deliberately installed will share a directory with ones that other people/programs installed, or which came with the OS, with no easy way for you to distinguish which is which

Instead, use something simply-named in your native natural language, like `~/programs` or `~/apps`.

Comment: This is not Linux, think you're on MacOS.

Comment: @stoney you don't know how to create a directory on Linux?