# Standard convention installation folder for GitEye on Linux and how to start it

Tags: linux, software-installation

I couldn't find an answer for this here already (maybe didn't know the right keywords to search for...) - my apologies if this kind of question have already been asked.

What about be a "good practice" folder to put GitEye for Linux installation in?

From what I read I thought /usr/local/GitEye might be the right place, but I'm not sure... (maybe lowercase giteye?).

Also, what would be the standard way to start it if I want a command-line shortcut (but not to add it to the path)? Should I make a symbolic link in /usr/bin/local?

Best regards!

Comment: I remember answering a [similar question here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127076/into-which-directory-should-i-install-programs-in-linux). For the symlink, it would be `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/bin` (which are not necessarily in the default path, this depends on the distribution).

Comment: So just to be sure I understand your answer - I should make a folder called GitEye under `/usr/local` or `/opt` and put all the unzipped content there, and create a symlink to the GitEye executable in `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/bin` respectively, correct?

Comment: Yes, `/opt` is the more usual place if everything must be in one directory. `/usr/local` is usually for software that respects the `bin` `lib` `share` organisation of files.

Comment: For Debian: https://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/06/09/how-to-install-giteye-git-client-on-debian-gnulinux-easy-guide/