# Can't Find Installed Software in Ubuntu Search

Tags: ubuntu, find, search

I have installed some software from downloaded files (not from a repo) but I would like to be able to find them through the Ubuntu search engine in order to have them available in my task bar.

For example : I have installed "sublimetext3" from apt-get, and when I press "Win" then type "Subl" the software appear, and I can pin it to task bar.

All my software are in ~/Softwares, a directory I have created.

How can I achieve this ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What and how did you install that software?

Comment: You probably need to create and install an appropriate *desktop entry* (.desktop file) - see for example [How can I add an application to the GNOME window manager?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103213/how-can-i-add-an-application-to-the-gnome-window-manager)

Comment: Thank you streeldriver, this was exactly my problem !
Kulfy : I installed it from a run file. The software is "Foxit Reader"