# Gnome 3 : How do I create a launcher in the dock?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome3

First of all, I saw [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103213/how-can-i-add-an-application-to-the-gnome-window-manager) and all the others with similar answer and it does not seem to work for me. I use **Ubuntu 19.04** and **GNOME 3.32.1**

I downloaded Postman (a code testing tool) and I want to be able to launch it from the dock. When I launch it from the shortcut, it appears in the dock:

[image]

But when I right-click it, I cannot add it to my favorites, which usually allows me to pin an application to the dock:
[image]

I also tried to add a desktop file to `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications` and make it executable, and then restarting gnome, but it did nothing. Desktop file :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Postman
Icon=/home/[my user name]/Utilities/Postman/app/resources/assets/icon.png
Exec=/home/[my user name]/Utilities/Postman/app/Postman
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;
```

Comment: You won't make a `.Desktop` file executable. Did you try little tool called `alacarte` to create a launcher ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that but yes I did, did not work either. Also I was able to give executable rights to a `.desktop` file.

Comment: example in GNOME documentation - https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en#ex-sample-desktop-file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok so I was able to add it to the dock following these steps. Add this desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications` as `postman.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Postman
Icon=/home/[my user name]/Utilities/Postman/app/resources/app/assets/icon.png
Exec=/home/[my user name]/Utilities/Postman/app/Postman
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;
```

then searching for "postman" via "Activities" (it only shows up there if you already created the `.desktop` file) and right click it > add to favorites.

Comment: This does not work for me on Ubunutu 20.04 (Gnome 3.36) -- I cannot find "postman" in "Activities".

Comment: Or rather:  it only works some of the time.  I've tried to pinpoint the problem, but it's escaping me.  Sometimes creating an exact copy of the desktop file (i.e. using file system copy operation) solves the issue, sometimes not.

Comment: relevant documentation: https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/

Comment: I am using Ubuntu version 21.04. It DID worked for me without any issues. That was sooo simple man!!! Thanks a lot for sharing. I created my icon/launcher for Android Studio to avoid run it manually from command line (nothing against command line - I love it actually, but...).

Comment: thanks, it works. but i find it baffling that a modern desktop environment does not provide a GUI for a basic thing like that out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

There are two places, where you can place your `*.desktop` file:

- `/usr/share/applications/`
- `~/.local/share/applications/`.

But if there is a `*.desktop` file of the same name in **both** locations and one of them has `Exec=...` pointing to a non-existent target, then you will not be able see any of the launchers in *Applications*.